# How to add borders in Images shown in Magento 1.7?

Tags: image, magento, border

How to add borders in Images shown in Magento 1.7?

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's more a CSS question, but you need to go to the main style file of you template located normally in skin/frontend/default/yourtheme/css/styles

there you need to modify the class img or create a new one:

```
.products-grid img {border: solid 1px #cccccc }
```

Something like that. Hope it gives you an idea